# Переходы многоязычного сайта

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста!
У меня одна проблема на сайте. Если я нахожусь например на /ru/about.php и хочу  перевести страницу на английский(или нажимаю иконку) то я попаду в /en/ на главную страницу. А я хочу чтобы я попало в /en/about.php. 
Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Ваш сайт работает на каком-то cms или фреймворке? или вы сами написали его?

Comment: Очевидно, в этой вашей иконке нужно прописать ссылку на /en/about.php :) А уж как это сделать - зависит от того, как эта иконка конкретно устроена

Comment: Мне просто нужно как-то узнать адрес  страницы в котором я нахожусь

Answer (score 0):

Прописывать абсолютные пути ссылок.
Рекомендую к изучению наглядную статью с картинками http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Comment: Неправильный (да и вредный) совет.